# How do I get the value of the column with the max data in a group by in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe which has multiple rows for each particular `user_id` and I'm trying to create a new dataframe that aggregates the values for each `user_id`. For example, the original dataframe `df` is

```
id    user_id      eventdate      col1       col2
1      100         2015-10-01      2          A
2      200         2015-11-01      4          B
3      300         2015-12-01      1          A
4      100         2016-02-01      3          B
5      300         2016-03-01      6          C
```

From this I want a new dataframe `df_agg` for each user like this:

```
user_id      col1_sum        col2_latest
100          5               B
200          4               B
300          7               C
```

I got the `col1_sum` by doing a groupby like this:

```
df_agg = pd.DataFrame({'col1_sum': df.groupby('NAME')['col1'].sum()})
```

How do I add the `col2_latest` column to this dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by `sum` and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last.html):

```
df_agg = df.groupby('user_id').agg({'col1':'sum','col2':'last'})
df_agg = df_agg[['col1','col2']].rename(columns={'col1':'col1_sum','col2':'col2_latest'})
                                .reset_index()
print (df_agg)
   user_id  col1_sum col2_latest
0      100         5           B
1      200         4           B
2      300         7           C
```

Comment: great. didn't realize there was a last() method. accepted.